# How can I browse answers sorted by votes?

Tags: support, answers, search, sorting

Is there any way to see a list of answers sorted by votes? I know I can [sort questions by votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes), but sometimes a not so well received question has an amazing answer. I'd like to simply browse highly rated answers to see what's garnered appreciation from the community. Is it possible?

If not, would this be a feature that others feel would be useful?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Simply search for `is:answer` (or `is:a` for short)  and then sort by votes ([direct link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3Aanswer)):

[image: Highly rated answers]

If you want to limit the answers to a certain tag, for example *Java*, then just add `[java]` to the search options. You can find more information on available search options in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

Comment: `is:a` and `is:q` also work if you're too lazy to type the whole thing.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: Good point, I added it to the answer.

Comment: Git related questions really take the top rankings heh

Comment: @Tschallacka to be honest... I had most of those git questions myself at some point, and found the answer on Stack Overflow. So I'm not surprised :)