# In a search query, what are the possibilities to sort the results?

Tags: feature-request, search, sorting

When defining a search query, I would also like to define the sort order.  I am, however, not yet sure what sort order would be most helpful for me, and thus I would like to know what options exist.

It seems that the query syntax does not provide such a possibility - at least there is nothing mentioned on the [page on advanced searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/advanced-search-parameters-jobs).  I did search through Stack Overflow META, but did not find any overview.

There is a possibility to add a sort option to the URL, as demonstrated in this question: [How can I browse answers sorted by votes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363225/how-can-i-browse-answers-sorted-by-votes).  Another option that can be used appears to be `tab=`, as is discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378188/5747415).  However, I did not find any documentation about what options could possibly be given to `sort=` or `tab=`. Thus the question:

What are the possibilities for sorting the results of queries?

I would be happy if the answer was only a link to a documentation page I have missed - in that case, however, it would be an improvement if this page was easier to find.  If there is not a documentation page yet, it would be an improvement for the site if one was created.

Answer (score 3):

If you are browsing a question list (homepage or tag), you have the following options:

- Newest
- Active
- Bounties
- Votes
- Frequent

[image]

Your last used sort option here is saved.

---

Specifically for search only, the `?tab=` parameter has these following options:

- relevance (default)
- newest
- votes
- active

[image]

Your last used search sort option is not saved, and will default to "relevance". You can pre-select a sort option before performing the search, as well as [save your last search sort option](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371678/584192) using [this userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/7971/9011) I made.

[image]